# How to use function for repeated code in ARM Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I have the follwing code in ARM assembly :

```
GetCharAtR1 LDRB r3,[r0,r1]     ;   Get character 1 at position pointed at by r1
            CMP r3,#'A'         ;   Check if character is not a letter 
            ADDLT r1,#1         
            BLT GetCharAtR1     
        
            CMP r3,#'z'         ;   check if character is not a letter
            ADDGT r1,#1             
            BGT GetCharAtR1         

            CMP r3,#'a'         
            ADDLT r3,#toLower   ;convert character to lowercase equivalent if its not

                            ; The following does the same as above but for r2 which points at the end of STRING
GetCharAtR2 LDRB r4,[r0,r2]     
            CMP r4,#'A'         
            SUBLT r2,#1         
            BLT GetCharAtR2         
        
            CMP r4,#'z'         
            SUBGT r2,#1         
            BGT GetCharAtR2         

            CMP r4,#'a'         
            ADDLT r4,#toLower
```

The two labels GetCharAtR1 and GetCharAtR2 are doing very similar things. Is it possible to remove the duplicate lines of code using functions or something else to achieve the same effects ?

Thanks

Comment: The usual way is to move `r2` into `r1` and make a function. Preserve any registers you need to.

Comment: Can you point to some link or give a short sample code..may be two or three lines...as I really struggle with assembly code...

Comment: How are the parameters passed in assembly ? It's like I push it somewhere and pop it out inside the function call ? So here I see  I will need to pass r1 and  r3  to the function and then r2 r4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to comments made no parameters and not specifically your code.

There is no calling convention in assembly, part of the beauty and freedom.  Compiler authors choose/create a calling convention so that the code will work together.  While a processor vendor may create a convention/specification understand this is a recommendation.  The authors are free to do what they want (the big ones like gcc tend to lean toward those specifications where present rather than roll their own (arm, x86, etc))

But for lack of a better solution you can simply use an existing convention, which you can get the documentation for but that spec is sometimes hard to read and understand, so in parallel or instead you can prototype these function skeletons in the high level language and see how the compiler handles it.

```
unsigned int fun0 ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    return((a<<1)|(b^3));
}
char fun1 ( char *p )
{
    return(p[3]);
}
unsigned int fun2 ( unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int);
void fun3 ( void )
{
    fun2(1,2,3);
}
```

build and disassemble, you can look at the compilers assembly language output but because of pseudo instructions and other things it is often best to compile then disassemble.

Note you have not specified your instruction set, making assumptions...

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   e2211003    eor r1, r1, #3
   4:   e1810080    orr r0, r1, r0, lsl #1
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

0000000c <fun1>:
   c:   e5d00003    ldrb    r0, [r0, #3]
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000014 <fun3>:
  14:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
  18:   e3a02003    mov r2, #3
  1c:   e3a01002    mov r1, #2
  20:   e3a00001    mov r0, #1
  24:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <fun2>
  28:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
  2c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

last one first, clearly in this case the first parameter is in r0, second in r1, third in r2.

and fun0 also indicates this and shows that r0 is the return register.

fun1 also indicates r0 is the passed pointer and r0 is the returned value.

Based on experience, the calling convention used for arm by gcc and some others r0-r3 are used for parameters first where possible (different sizes and types of variables may cause some of these to be skipped).  but also r0-r3 are volatile meaning the function does not need to preserve their values but r4,r5,r6...need to be preserved meaning if you use them (change them) you need to save them somewhere (the stack) and put them back the way you found them before returning to the caller.